# Can we access to a list of available contexts to an object in java?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jvm, java-ee-8

We know that we have many types of context in java.

Regardless of what these types can do and where to use them, i want to know is there any way to get a list of available current contexts programmatically?

assume that a client calls a transactional web service. this service calls a method in EJB and so on. in the chain of invocations container create some type of contexts. with this assumption i want to know what type of context is available to use in current EJB(or any other object in the chain of method invocations).

is there any solution for this?

Comment: For each case you should use different logic.

Comment: Do they having anything in common besides the word `Context` in their name, i.e. something that justifies the assumption that there has to be a such feature?

Comment: please read the question carefully, did you get the mean?

Comment: Programming means to explain a machine what to do. If you can’t express your requirements in a way that a machines understands it, there can’t be program solving your problem. Considering something a “type of context” by yourself, is incomprehensible to a machine. There’s a potentially infinite number of classes fitting into the pattern of forming some kind of context. I could create a new one this afternoon. So how is a JVM supposed to understand what you consider a context and why should it consider it special enough to have a built-in function to collect them into a list?